# Tab CSS Conflict between Theme and Plugin's CSS Style

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I am trying to show tabs on http://bit.ly/YXjVDG

first set of tabs are displayed using theme's own shortcode :

```
Real Estate In Hollywood Land
Nearby Schools
Local Businesses
Real Estate Market Trends
```

now if you click on the Nearby Schools tab, there are three more tabs which I had shown using the "Simple Real Estate Plugin" and modified its tab display code to match the css of the theme. Now here is what is happening:

Tabs are displayed correctly but none of them are active tab. 1st tab should be active by default as it happens when I use theme's tab shortcode.

Here is the default layout HTML for displaying the tabs from theme :

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="Neighborhood0" class="tab-pane active"></div>
        <div id="Neighborhood1" class="tab-pane"></div>
        <div id="Neighborhood2" class="tab-pane "></div>
        <div id="Neighborhood3" class="tab-pane "></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the plugin's file which I modified to match the CSS of the theme's tab:

```
<?php
define('EDU_API_URL', 'http://api.education.com/service/service.php');
define('EDU_API_KEY', 'XXXXXXX');
define('RESF', 'xml');

function srp_education_get_api_key(){
        return EDU_API_KEY;
}

function _srp_get_query_url($args = array()){
  global $srp_scripts;
  $srp_scripts = true;

    if(is_array($args) && count($args)>0){
        $i = 0;
        $q = NULL;

        //distance parameter is invalid if lat/lng is not setup
        if( !isset($args['latitude']) )
            unset($args['distance']);

        //distance is required if lat/lng is set
        if( isset($args['latitude']) && isset($args['longitude']) )
            $args['distance'] = isset($args['distance']) ? $args['distance'] : 3;

    $query = '';
        foreach($args as $key => $value){
            if(!$value){
                return;
            }
            if($i > 0){
                $q = '&';
            }
            $query .= $q . $key . '=' . str_replace(' ', '+', $value);
            $i++;
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
// Create function_name_output() specific to each function
function srp_get_apiFunction($function_name){
    $api_funcs = array(
        'schoolSearch' => array(
            'required'  => array(
                'sn'    => 'sf',
                'f'     => 'schoolSearch',
                'key'   => EDU_API_KEY,
                'resf'  => RESF,
            ),
            'optional'  => array(
                'schoolid', 'districtid', 'zip', 'city', 'state', 'distance', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'minResult',
            ),
            'return'    => array(),
        ),


        'districtSearch' => array(
            'required'  => array(
                'sn'    => 'sf',
                'f'     => 'districtSearch',
                'key'   => EDU_API_KEY,
                'resf'  => RESF,
            ),
            'optional'  => array(
                'districtid', 'districtname', 'zip', 'city', 'state',
            ),
            'return'    => array(),
        ),


        'numberOf' => array(
            'required'  => array(
                'sn'    => 'sf',
                'f'     => 'numberOf',
                'key'   => EDU_API_KEY,
                'resf'  => RESF,
                'city'  => false,
                'state' => false,
            ),
            'optional'  => array(),
            'return'    => array(),
        ),

                'gbd' => array(
            'required'  => array(
                'sn'    => 'sf',
                'f' => 'gbd',
                'key'   => EDU_API_KEY,
                'resf'  => RESF,
            ),
            'optional'  => array( 'city', 'state'),
            'return'    => array(),
        ),


    );

    foreach($api_funcs[$function_name]['required'] as $key => $val){
        if(empty($api_funcs[$function_name]['required'][$key])){
            $empty[] = $key;
        }
    }
    if( isset($empty) ){
        $keys = implode(', ', $empty);
        echo '<div class="error">Education API paramenters [' . $keys . '] for function ' . $function_name. '() were not found. Please check the Plugin Settings.</div>';
        die();
    }
    return $api_funcs[$function_name];
}

function srp_run_apiFunction($function_name, $arguments=array()){
    $function = srp_get_apiFunction($function_name);
        $required = array();
        $optional = array();

        //checking required options against arguments
        foreach($arguments as $arg=>$value){

            if(in_array($arg, array_keys($function['required']))){
                $function['required'][$arg] = $value;
            }
        }
        $required = $function['required'];

        //checking optional parameters agains arguments
        foreach($arguments as $arg=>$value){
            if(in_array($arg, $function['optional'])){
                $optional[$arg] = $value;
            }
        }

        if(!empty($required) && !empty($optional)){
                    $url = EDU_API_URL . '?' . _srp_get_query_url($required) . '&' . _srp_get_query_url($optional);

                    if(!$xml = srp_wp_http_xml($url)){
                        return;
                    }
                    return $xml;
               }
}

function srp_groupSchoolsBy($args){
    $location = $args['location'];
    $xml = srp_run_apiFunction('schoolSearch', $location);
    if($xml){
        $schools = array();
        $i=0;
        //pa($xml);
        foreach($xml->record as $item){
            //if($i> 5){ break; }
            $school = $item->school;
            $group = (string)$school->$args['groupby'];
            $group = explode(',', $group);
            $group = array_unique($group);
                        if(is_array($group)){
                            foreach($group as $name){
                                    if($name != ''){
                                            $schools[$name][] = $item;
                                    }
                            }
                            $i++;
                            unset($group);
                        }
        }
                if(!empty($schools))
                    return $schools;

                return;
    }
        return;
}

function srp_tabs_byType($args = array(), $ajax = NULL){
    if(empty($args)) { return; }

    //don't display distance radius for city/zip code searches
    if ( isset($args['location']['distance']) &&
            ( isset($args['location']['latitude']) && isset($args['location']['longitude']) )
        )
    {
        $distance = $args['location']['distance'];
    }

    if(!$types = srp_groupSchoolsBy($args)) {
            if($distance){
                $message = "<p class='no-schools-found'>There are no schools within {$distance} miles radius of this location.</p>";
            }else{
                $message = "<p class='no-schools-found'>There are no schools near by this property.</p>";
            }
            if($ajax){
                return serialize(array('message' => $message, 'markers' => array()));
            }
            return $message;
        }
    $html_arr = array();
    $titles = array_keys($types);
    $coordinates = array();

    $i = 0;
    $list = false;
    $table = false;
    $tabs = false;
    foreach($types as $type){
        $groups[$i] = $titles[$i];
        $totals[$i] = count($type);
        $tabids[$i] = 1 + $i;

        $i++;
        $total = count($type);
        $name = $titles[$i-1];
        $$args['output'] .= '<div class="tab-pane " id="tabs-' . $i . '">' . "\n";
        $location = false;
        $in = false;

        if( !isset($args['location']['location_title']) ){
            if ( isset($args['location']['city']) )
                $location .= $args['location']['city'];

            if ( $location && isset($args['location']['state']) )
                $location .= ', ' . $args['location']['state'];

            if ( isset($args['location']['zip']) )
                $location .= ' ' . $args['location']['zip'];

            if ($location)
                $in = ' in ';

            $td_distance_header = false;
        }elseif($args['location']['location_title']){
            $location = $args['location']['location_title'];
            $in = ' near ';
            $td_distance_header = '<th scope="col" class="school_field_center">Distance (mi)</th>';
        }elseif(!$args['location']['latitude'] && !$args['location']['longitude']){
            $in = ' near ';
            $td_distance_header = '<th scope="col" class="school_field_center">Distance (mi)</th>';
        }
        $$args['output'] .= "<h3>$name Schools $in $location</h3>";
        if($distance){
            $$args['output'] .= "<p class='schools-found'>$total $name Schools found within $distance miles radius.</p>\n";
        }else{
            $$args['output'] .= "<p class='schools-found'>$total $name Schools found in the area.</p>\n";
        }
        $list .= "\t<ul>\n";
        $table .= '<table class="srp_table tableStyle SchoolsByType">
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 40%">School</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="school_field_center" style="width: 20%">Type</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="school_field_center" style="width: 20%">Grade Level</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="school_field_center" style="width: 20%">Enrollment</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="school_field_center" style="width: 20%">Students per Teacher</th>'
                        .$td_distance_header.
                    '</tr>'."\n";
        $x = 0;
        foreach($type as $item){
            if($x%2){ $even_odd = "even"; } else { $even_odd = "odd"; }
            $school = $item->school;
                        if(!isset($city) && !isset($state) && $school->city){
                            $city = $school->city;
                            $state = $school->state;
                        }
            $list .= "\t\t<li>" . $school->schoolname . ' <br /> Phone: ' . $school->phonenumber . '<br />' . $school->address . ', ' . $school->city . ', ' . $school->state . $school->zip . "</li>\n";

            $td_distance = false;
            if($td_distance_header){
                $td_distance = '<td class="school_field_center">'.round((float)$school->distance, 2).'</td>';
            }

                        $website = null;
                        if($school->website != ""){
                            $website = ' <a href="http://' . $school->website . '" target="_blank">' . $school->website . '</a>';
                        }
            $table .= "<tr class=\"$even_odd\">
                        <td class=\"school_address\"><a href=\"$school->url\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"><span class=\"school_name\">$school->schoolname</span></a><br />Phone: $school->phonenumber<br />$school->address, $school->city, $school->state $school->zip". $website ."</td>
                        <td class=\"school_field_center\">$school->schooltype</td>
                        <td class=\"school_field_center\">$school->gradesserved</td>
                        <td class=\"school_field_center\">$school->enrollment</td>
                        <td class=\"school_field_center\">$school->studentteacherratio</td>
                        $td_distance
                      </tr>\n";

            //$coordinates[] = '"' . $school->latitude .'|'. $school->longitude . '|<div><span class=\"school_name\">'.$school->schoolname.'</span><br />'.$school->schooltype . ' - ' . $school->gradesserved .'<br />Phone: '.$school->phonenumber.'<br />'.$school->address.', '. $school->city.', '.$school->state.' '. $school->zip.'</div>' . '"';
            $schoolname = (string)$school->schoolname;
            $coordinates[$schoolname]['lat'] = (string)$school->latitude;
            $coordinates[$schoolname]['lng'] = (string)$school->longitude;
            $coordinates[$schoolname]['html'] = '<div style="width: 315px; min-height: 70px; font-size: 12px;line-height: normal;">
                            <span class="school_name">'.$school->schoolname.'</span>
                                <br />'.$school->schooltype . ' - ' . $school->gradesserved
                                .'<br />Phone: '.$school->phonenumber
                                .'<br />'.$school->address.', '
                                . $school->city.', '
                                .$school->state.' '
                                . $school->zip
                                .'</div>';
            $x++;
        }
        $list .= "\t<ul>\n";
        $table .= "</table>\n";
        $$args['output'] .= "</div>\n";

    }

    //$coords = implode(', ', $coordinates);
    if($list || $table){
        //Generating Tabs
        $tabs .= "<ul class=\"nav nav-tabs\">\n";
        arsort($totals);

        foreach($totals as $id => $total){

            $tabs .= "\t\t" . '<li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-' .  $tabids[$id] . '">' .$groups[$id] . ' (' . $total . ') </a></li>' . "\n";
        }
        $tabs .= "</ul>\n";
        $tabs .= '<div class="tab-content">' . "\n";

        //add disclaimer to the footer
        add_action('srp_footer_disclaimers', 'srp_Education_disclaimer');
        $output = '<div class="tabs">' . srp_Education_attribution($school->city, $school->state) . "\n" . $tabs . $$args['output'] . '</div></div>' . "\n";
        if($ajax){
            $content = $output;
            return serialize(array('markers' => $coordinates));//, 'content' => $content));
        }else{
            return $output;
        }
    }
}

//Seann Birkelund @ sbirkelund@education.com
//allowed to nofollow disclaimer links, but not the attribution links within the content from the Education.com
function srp_Education_disclaimer(){
    $content = '<div class="spr_disclaimer srp_education_disclaimer">&copy; <a href="http://www.education.com/" rel="nofollow">Education.com, Inc.</a> 2008.&nbsp; Use is subject to <a href="http://www.education.com/schoolfinder/tools/webservice/terms/" rel="nofollow">Terms of Service</a></div>';
    echo $content;
}

function srp_Education_attribution($city=false, $state=false){
    if($city && $state){
        $xml = srp_run_apiFunction('gbd', array('city' => $city, 'state' => $state));
        $link = '<a href="' . $xml->lsc . '">See more information on ' . $city . ' schools from Education.com </a>';
    }else{
        $link = '<a href="http://www.education.com/schoolfinder/">See more school information from Education.com</a>';
    }
    $content = '<div id="srp_Education_attr">Data provided by <a href="http://www.education.com/schoolfinder/"><img src="'. SRP_IMG .'/branding/edu-logo-75x31.jpg" width="75" height="31" alt="Education.com Logo"></a><br />
'. $link .'</div>';
    return $content;
}

function srp_getSchools_ajax(){
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];

    $radius = srp_get_radius('schools', false);
    if ($radius == false)
    {
        $radius = 3;
    }
    $address = NULL; //$_POST['address'];

    if($result = srp_schoolSearch_shortcode(array("lat"=>$lat,  "lng"=>$lng, "distance"=>$radius, "groupby"=>"gradelevel", "output"=>"table", "location_title"=>$address), $ajax = true)){
        $result = unserialize($result);
        $result = json_encode($result);
        die($result);
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_srp_getSchools_ajax', 'srp_getSchools_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_srp_getSchools_ajax', 'srp_getSchools_ajax');

function _schools_checkbox(){
    return '<input id="schools_select" type="checkbox"><label for="schools_select">Schools</label><br />' . "\n";
}
add_filter('_add_to_yelpselect', '_schools_checkbox');

?>
```

How do I make the default tab active?

Comment: In the `if($list || $table)` part, first of all why the \" \" ? You could use `$tabs .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">\n';` no? Also try adding a class in `$tabs .=` part: `$tabs .= "\t\t" . '<li class="tab-pane"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-' .  $tabids[$id] . '">' .$groups[$id] . ' (' . $total . ') </a></li>' . "\n";`.

When you select it it gets a class, so maybe it not having any class in the first place is messing something up, and not assigning an active class in the first place.

Comment: I am sorry but this did not help and website does not open once I add the changes mentioned above. I tried adding a class to <li> but that did not help too. The lists are showing in tabs but just the first tab is not active. I have to click on it to make it active.

Comment: Ok, my bad for the first one. Your site shows many jquery errors. In srp.js there is an error on the line 522 
function srp_refresh_tabs(selector){
    if( jQuery(selector).length > 0 )
    jQuery(selector).tabs();

Comment: I realize there are many errors on the file. but I just ran a quick test on http://www.jshint.com/ and it did not give the error on 522. I am still learning JQuery and if you can help me correct this that would be awesome.

Comment: First try to fix the cnss.js error. In your wp-content/plugins/easy-social-icons/js there should be cnss.js file, if there isn't then find it online and upload it. I looked at that whole .js file, and there are some semicolons missing, but apart from that I don't see what could be an issue. I'm not an expert at jquery myself :\